# A Matrix with Every Second Entry 0

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ such that $M_{ij} = 0$ if $i$ and $j$ are of odd parity (that is to say that if $i$ is even, then $j$ is odd and vice versa). As such, my matrix will look something like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
* & 0 & * & 0 & * & \cdots & \\
0 & * & 0 & * & 0 & \cdots & \\
\vdots \\
\vdots 
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
$$

where $*$ is just a numerical place holder. What are these matrices called, and further more are there any interesting properties under certain conditions that have been shown / proven? I'm very interested in its eigenvalues. Unfortunately I have no extra background information to give as I do not know where to start looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap rows and columns, such that your matrix becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&\ldots&*&0&\ldots&0\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\*&\ldots&*&0&\ldots&0\\0&\ldots&0&*&\ldots&*\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0&\ldots&0&*&\ldots&*\\\end{pmatrix}$$
This is now a so-called block-diagonal matrix. In particular, the eigenvalues of this matrix are the eigenvalues of both blocks. Hence, your eigenvalue problem decomposes into two smaller eigenvalue problems.